# Ошибка: "Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts"

Tags: c#, sql

Появилась ошибка, помогите решить. Вот у меня есть код

```
  public static string host, database, user, password;
    public static string strProvider;

    public news()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        host = Settings.Default.host;
        password = Settings.Default.password;
        database = Settings.Default.database;
        user = Settings.Default.username;
        //Данные по умолчанию.
        //host = "localhost"
        //password = "159357"
        //database = "admin"
        //user = "admin"

        strProvider = "Data Source=" + host + ";Database=" + database + ";User ID=" + user + ";Password=" + password;
    }
```

Это у меня тут строка подключения, а этот код должен добавить новость в БД, но пишет ошибку
**Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.**

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MySqlConnection cnt = new MySqlConnection(strProvider);
        try
        {
            cnt.Open();
            MessageBox.Show("Подключение прошло успешно");
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO news (title, body, date) VALUES('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + richTextBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "');", cnt);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cnt.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Новость успешно добавлена");

        }
        catch(MySqlException  ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Не удалось подключится к БД", ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE** изменил код, при нажатии на button1

Comment: ну пожалуйста, никогда, НИКОГДА, не делайте конкатенацию строк для SQL запросов! [Работа с подключенным уровнем ADO .NET в C#](http://www.cyberforum.ru/ado-net/thread182279.html)

Comment: Можно узнать значение слова **конкатенацию**

Comment: Конкатена́ция (сцепле́ние) — операция склеивания объектов линейной структуры, обычно строк. Например, конкатенация слов «микро» и «мир» даст слово «микромир».

еле нашёл

Comment: А где вы её заметили у меня в коде? Да и там как-то странно он подключается к БД.... мне нужно к БД MySQL, а не локальной.

Comment: Все для денвера все нормально подключается(моя вина забыл запустить его), а для других БД не подключается... которе не на денвере, а в инете.

Comment: В данном коде конкатенация строк производится при создании MySqlCommand.

Comment: @Angus123 у БД в инете почти всегда отключена возможность удаленного подключения, общайтесь с хостером.

Comment: Но почему же? В PHP файлах я указываю те же данные для подключения и он подключается без проблем... а в программе чего-то не хочет.

Comment: В php-файлах на хостинге подключение к БД на хостинге - локальное либо входит в список разрешенных. Если вы с денвера сможете соединиться с БД на хостинге - тогда да, дело в проге.

Answer (score 1):

Передайте ваш объект соединения с БД (cnt) в конструктор объекта MySqlCommand:

```
new MySqlCommand("query", cnt);
```

Comment: А можно по подробнее насчет query? Или полный код... а то я не совсем понял что надо переделать..

Comment: а разве в коде по-другому?

Comment: Ой это я просто ваш код добавил... щяс верну каким он был.

Comment: С данным изменением код заработал?

Comment: да какие изменения? всё было точно так же? о чём вы?